# FullSimplify assumptions for function body

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I'd like to pass an assumption to `FullSimplify` so whenever it gets a function that is squared and square rooted would return me only the function body, without `Abs[f]` (I've tried assumption `_Symbol ∈ Reals && _Symbol > 0` but it gives `Abs[f]` instead of `f`.

```
f[x_] := a x^2;
FullSimplify[Sqrt[f[x]^2], _Symbol ∈ Reals && _Symbol > 0]
```

> ```
> x^2 Abs[a]
> ```

Comment: `FullSimplify[Sqrt[f[x]^2], _Symbol \[Element] Reals] /. Abs[v_] -> v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[f[x]^2], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, PowerExpand}]
```

Comment: That's exactly the kind of fix I've been looking for! Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the syntax you have used in the second argument of `FullSimplify`. How about the following

```
Clear@f
f[x_] := a x^2;
FullSimplify[Sqrt[f[x]^2], 
 x \[Element] Reals && x > 0 && a \[Element] Reals && a > 0]
```

> ```
> a x^2
> ```

Comment: I'd like it to work with any function, not just a function with "a" and "x"

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for any symbols):

```
Unprotect[Greater];
SetAttributes[Greater, {Listable}];
f[x_] := b a x^2;
list = Cases[f[x], _Symbol];
FullSimplify[
 Sqrt[f[x]^2], _Symbol \[Element] Reals && And @@ Greater[list, 0]]

(*   a b x^2      *)
```

Comment: Nice, but could have unpredictable consequences..